# Javascript: Function inside object not working

Tags: javascript, function, object, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to create a controller in Javascript, which will respond to button clicks and change the view accordingly.

I have a function which works that looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function () { 
    //do something

   };
```

However, when I try to put the function in a controller object, I get an "unexpected token" error:

```
var controller = {
  this.reset = document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function () { 
    //do something

   };
}
```

I'm not sure about 2 things:

1. How to fix this error? (I know its due to scope, but don't know how to fix it in a way that still follows MVC patterns)
2. Generally speaking, is this a good way to go about creating a controller object? (I'm new to the MVC model, and don't know if I'm following best practices.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to that the object cant be declared like that, there are different ways to do it:

```
var obj1 = { 
    a : function() { 
        console.log('obj1'); 
    } 
};

var obj2 = function() { 
    var b = function() { 
        console.log('obj2');
    };

    return { 
        a: b
    }
};

var obj3 = function() {
    this.a = function() { 
        console.log('obj3'); 
     } 
};
```

And then use it.

```
obj1.a; //prints obj1
obj2().a; //prints obj2
new obj3().a; //prints obj3.
```

About how to structure your objects is opinion based, but i like to do it like this.

```
var Controller = function() {
    this.attachEvents = function() {
        document.getElementById("reset").onclick = reset;
    }

    var reset = function() {
        console.log('reset');
    };
}
new Controller().attachEvents();
```

another option is..

```
var Controller = function() {
    this.reset = function() {
        console.log('reset');
    };
}
var controller = new Controller();
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = controller.reset;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid Javascript object structure, but you can do it in following if it works for you

```
var controller = {
  reset : function () { 
    document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(){
       //do your work here
     }
   }
}
```

Logic is completely on you/developer how he/she wants to handle things.

or you can do the binding thing outside, like,

```
var controller = {
      reset : function () { 
         //what to do to rsest
       }
    }
```

and then, bind it elsewhere

```
//when to run reset method
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = controller.reset;
```